# Uploading files to Amazon S3 with PHP ends up with a 28 byte file

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on a project where users can upload files to the site that is stored in an Amazon S3 bucket.

This doesn't really work though.. The server sees the file and everything seems good, apart from the file only being 28 bytes big when it ends up on amazon..

This is my code so far:

**controller**

```
public function uploadFile()
{
    $data['username'] = $this->input->cookie('username', TRUE);
    $data['pagetitle'] = "Upload file";
    $data['userid'] = $this->userid;

    $this->load->template('uploadFile', $data);
}

public function takeUpload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './images/screenshots/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $projectFileLoc = $_FILES['projectFile']['tmp_name'];
    $projectFileName = $_FILES['projectFile']['name'];

    if (!($this->upload->do_upload("previewImage")) && !($this->s3->putObject($projectFileLoc, '3dnation', $projectFileName, $this->s3->ACL_PUBLIC_READ)))
    {
        echo "Something went wrong...";
    }
    else
    {
        $imgData = $this->upload->data();
        $previewImage = $imgData['file_name'];
        //TODO: Add image to DB
    }
}
```

**The view file (uploadFile.php)**

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Upload files</h1>
      </div>
    </div><!--/span-->
  </div><!--/row-->

  <div class="row">
    <div class "col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <form action="/home/takeUpload" method="POST" role="form" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title" name="title" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="description" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="textfield" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="Enter a description here" name="description" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="projectFile" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Project/Scene files (accepted formats: zip, rar, 3ds)</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="file" class="form-control" id="projectFile" name="projectFile" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="previewImage" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Preview image</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="file" class="form-control" id="previewImage" name="previewImage" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Upload</button>
                </div>
              </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I am building it with the latest Codeigniter with [this S3 library](https://github.com/psugand/CodeIgniter-S3)

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call to putObject with an array, if you want use a file you must call too "putObjectFile" function:

Check the definition in the class:

```
public static function putObjectFile($file, $bucket, $uri, $acl = self::ACL_PRIVATE, $metaHeaders = array(), $contentType = null)
{
     return self::putObject(self::inputFile($file), $bucket, $uri, $acl, $metaHeaders, $contentType);
}
```

A example from the original library:

```
// Simple PUT:
if (S3::putObject(S3::inputFile($file), $bucket, $uri, S3::ACL_PRIVATE)) {
    echo "File uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Failed to upload file.";
}
```

As you can see in the [doc](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/documentation#putObject)

Comment: Hah, thanks.. Just saw that it was a legacy function, and therefore it didn't seem right to use it, but it works..